Casement crank out Windows have 6 holes but no screen
We bought a house but just realized all the windows are casement crank out Windows without screen. Noticed all of them have 6 slots or holes around the inside edge.
Are they for weep hole? Or are they for some kind of window screen? If so, how can I buy them?


Thanks!

Have slightly similar windows and think my screens lock/fit into those holes with spring pins.  I would try local window stores and see if they know.

Weep holes are found on the bottom.

Check in the attic to see if they've been stored there (happened to me). Those holes are for mounting the screens into the frames using the spring pins on the screens.  Check around the opened windows for a name or manufacturer. You can also google "screen makers" and get companies that will custom make screens.

This is true, but also, making your own screens is not beyond the typical DIY skillset, and the savings can be substantial. For one window, I'll go to a local shop. For all windows in a house? Buy the materials and make your own.

True true. I found them all in the basement. Thank you!
